# move or refactor all open editor tabs (the corresponding files)

Tags: eclipse, ide, intellij-idea, refactoring

I need to change the package for a number of classes and interfaces that live in a number of different directories.

It is easy to open the files as tabs (as they are dependent on each other), but [I could not find any way](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-editor-tabs.html) to **do Refactor -> Move.. for all the opened tabs**?

- Is there a quicker way to manually going through all the tabs?
- I could not find a way to select multiple tabs?
- Might [tab groups](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editing-multiple-files-using-groups-of-tabs.html) be useful?
- I would like to do it in IntelliJ IDEA, but if that is not possible then Eclipse would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to have a refactoring act only upon open tabs in IntelliJ IDEA. It's a feature I have an [open request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14572) for. If your classes have some sort of common naming convention(s), you could define a [scope](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/scopes.html), use that scope in the project view to show all the classes, select all, and then run the move refactor. Shy of that, I'm afraid the only way is to go down one by one and select each class in the Project view using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to make multiple selections.